# Toggle variable number of table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table where clicking a link should show 'subrows' that belong to the data in the row clicked.

Since the subrows number may vary from 0 to n I think I should calculate the number of subrows by the `.val` method, is this right? So the value should be the number of invisble rows with class name 'affiliated' until the next `tr` without a class name. How can I do this?
I made some attempts but I'm pretty new to jQuery.

I thought something like this to calculate the number of tr.affiliated:

```
 var affiliatednumber = $(this).find("tr.affiliated").val().stop();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6t6QT/)

Comment: Why don't you use the ID attribute? would probably make your life a lot easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6t6QT/2/

Your use of `.val` and `.stop` don't make sense, and you are not using an input but an `a`.  I used `.nextUntil` since the rows will be grouped together; just find the closest parent row of the `a` (this is the "master" row) and use `.nextUntil` to find its affiliated rows -- next until the other master row.  It would also help if the master rows had their own class.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, still learning a lot, one of my first things I've been trying to write. Solution looks good and does not require any html changes. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again for this, but I found a 'bug', sometimes I need the data of two tr's together. In this case John and John's wife, the problem is that the closest method is not working anymore then, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/6t6QT/2/ How can I fix this?

Comment: @user1901096 I don't see anything about John's wife .. did you mean to post a separate link?

Comment: Sorry, apparently didn't save, this one should work: http://jsfiddle.net/6t6QT/7/ . The John/John's wife subrows are not showing while the Claire subrows are. I guess this is because of the closest method?

Comment: @user1901096 Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/6t6QT/8/ -- it will look for the next affiliate rows based on `rowspan`.  At this point it's getting a bit complicated, though.  It may be better to just change your markup and group the master/affiliate rows in `tbody` together.

Comment: Great, thanks! Looks complicated (for me at least) indeed. Will go into the code a bit deeper and learn as much as I can from it.

Answer (score 8):

If you put a class on each parent `tr` you can use `nextUntil()` like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td>John</td>
        <td>HR Admin</td>
        <td>10/10/1980</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td><a class="showaffiliated" href="#">Yes</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="affiliated">
        <td colspan="2">Amanda</td>
        <td colspan="3">20/20/1985</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="affiliated">
        <td colspan="2">Louis</td>
        <td colspan="3">20/10/2010</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```js
$("tr.affiliated").hide();

$("a.showaffiliated").click(function() {
    var $affiliated = $(this).closest(".parent").nextUntil(".parent");
    $affiliated.toggle();
    var affiliatednumber = $affiliated.length;
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6t6QT/1/)

Comment: Nice - I wasn't even aware of the nextUntil() method. Learn something new everyday :)

Comment: Even though the answer is correct, `nextUntil()` is a very inefficient method ([link](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/#comment-29884718)). A better solution would be to group the subrows in a `tbody` and toggle that.

Comment: thanks for the solution, could add a class, although the other solution does not need one. Thanks for the help, appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry to bother again with this but I found a 'bug' where the .closest method is not working anymore. Sometime two tr's can belong together, as with the example of John and John's wife but which doesn't show the subrows anymore.. How can I fix this? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6t6QT/6/